# What is "return can't jump across threads" error mean?

Tags: ruby, function, puppet

I have a pair of Puppet custom functions, one of which, namely am_func_cluster, returns a hash of array of currently running instances (reading a file as input) and the second one call that function, iterate over the array and returns the first successful one that listening to port 22. Here is the 2nd function:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:am_func_head, :type => :rvalue ) do |args|

        Puppet::Parser::Functions.function('am_func_cluster')
        mCls = function_am_func_cluster(['/opt/running-inst.txt'])
        cls = args[0].to_sym if args[0].is_a? String

        require 'socket'
        require 'timeout'

        mCls[cls].each do |dns|

           begin
               Timeout::timeout(1) { TCPSocket.new(dns, 22)
                    return (dns if mCls.key?(cls)) || 'undefined'
               }
               break
               rescue SocketError
               rescue Timeout::Error
           end
        end
    end
end
```

upon running, it returns this error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: return can't jump across threads at
>   /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:19 on node ip-10-0-9-130.xxx

It works just fine, if I comment out the `begin ... end` bit in the script. Google didn't favor much in this case, so far. Does anyone one know what that error means or what am I doing wrong. Still don't find myself very efficient understanding the errors returned by Ruby. Any pointer much appreciated. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you cannot use `return` there. Use `break` to escape from the timeout block:

```
require "timeout"
Timeout.timeout(3){break "foo"}
# => "foo"
```

and you should not use `break` outside of it.

As a general tip, it is easy to confuse `return`, `break`, and `next`. If one of them does not work, try another.

Comment: thanks @sawa: I still can't quite figure out. Used `break` inside the `Timeout ... }` and returned the `dns` just before exiting `mCls[cls].each do |$dns|` loop - didn't change anything. I'm sure I'm doing wrong. Any chance you put together a few line of sample code? Cheers!!

Comment: I'm certainly missing something here: How do I return the correct value from the `mCls[cls].each do |dns|` loop then? It should be the the very first element from the array that establishes the connection, before breaking out. Cheers!!